# I want to change border color of textfield using itemId

Tags: extjs4.1

```
{
xtype: 'textfield',
itemId: 'dueDate'
}
```

---

I have above code, I have to change the border colour of the **textfield**. So I tried to use `Ext.getDom('dueDate');` to get the Dom element. Unfortunately it is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

border: 5,
style: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderStyle: 'solid'
}

You need to specify border color and style.